# Ubuntu 16.04.3 Wifi not connecting; router need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets')

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, network-manager

I'm quite new to Ubuntu, here are some of the things about my issue:

1. currently cannot connect to a wifi router, that I haven't connected to before with this laptop.
2. My android phone connects fine to the same wifi (same password)
3. My laptop connected fine with wifi networks prior to this network
4. a couple days ago I updated "Ubuntu Software" with a GUI that popped up, I usually update by: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
5. My history log has these two particular updates:

   1. `gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0:amd64 (1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.2)`
   2. `network-manager:amd64 (1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.2)`
6. `nm-appplet` give me the following message:

   ```
   nm-applet-Message: No keyring secrets found for estudio/802-1x; asking user.
   ```

I tried doing the Ubuntu 17.04 solution (given my problem seems very similar) by going to:

*/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*

and adding a conf file with:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=0
```

(also `tried=no`, also tried changing *NewtworkManager.conf*)

```
ubuntu@ThinkPad-T470s:NetworkManager$ ifconfig
enp0s31f6 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 54:e1:ad:2f:7a:5d 
inet addr:192.168.1.4 Bcast:192.168.1.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
inet6 addr: fe80::4c94:8a27:a997:640f/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:1228044 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:663125 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:1747484374 (1.7 GB) TX bytes:67594382 (67.5 MB)
Interrupt:16 Memory:ec100000-ec120000 

lo Link encap:Local Loopback 
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
RX packets:462938 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:462938 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:23588608 (23.5 MB) TX bytes:23588608 (23.5 MB)

wlp58s0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr ac:ed:5c:04:49:ad 
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

PS: my ubuntu Version is 16.04.3

#### Some more info

I have this "problem" for a particular router 'estudio' that I could connect to with my android phone. The difference between both 'estudio' and 'Netgear' is that estudio says it "has secrets" while 'Netgear' says I already have those secrets. I have no idea how to address this. Here are my network logs(for both non-working 'estudion, and working 'Netgear':

```
Dec 24 01:45:07 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514090707.7167] device (enp0s31f6): Activation: successful, device activated.
Dec 24 01:59:49 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514091589.9586] keyfile: update /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/estudio (cee37fa1-b4a9-4171-bf31-c97af969501c,"estudio")
Dec 24 01:59:49 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514091589.9595] audit: op="connection-update" uuid="cee37fa1-b4a9-4171-bf31-c97af969501c" name="estudio" pid=6307 uid=1000 result="success"
Dec 24 01:59:52 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514091592.0476] device (wlp58s0): Activation: starting connection 'estudio' (cee37fa1-b4a9-4171-bf31-c97af969501c)
Dec 24 01:59:52 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514091592.0488] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="cee37fa1-b4a9-4171-bf31-c97af969501c" name="estudio" pid=5690 uid=1000 result="success"
Dec 24 01:59:52 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514091592.0492] device (wlp58s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Dec 24 01:59:52 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514091592.0510] device (wlp58s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Dec 24 01:59:52 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514091592.0528] device (wlp58s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'estudio' has security, but secrets are required.
Dec 24 01:59:52 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514091592.0529] device (wlp58s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Dec 24 01:59:56 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514091596.4616] keyfile: update /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/estudio (cee37fa1-b4a9-4171-bf31-c97af969501c,"estudio")
Dec 24 01:59:56 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514091596.4707] device (wlp58s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Dec 24 01:59:56 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514091596.4715] device (wlp58s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Dec 24 01:59:56 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514091596.4722] device (wlp58s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'estudio' has security, but secrets are required.
Dec 24 01:59:56 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514091596.4725] device (wlp58s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Dec 24 01:59:58 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <warn>  [1514091598.1107] device (wlp58s0): User canceled the secrets request.
Dec 24 01:59:58 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514091598.1108] device (wlp58s0): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets') [60 120 7]
Dec 24 01:59:58 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <warn>  [1514091598.1126] device (wlp58s0): Activation: failed for connection 'estudio'
Dec 24 01:59:58 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514091598.1161] device (wlp58s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Dec 24 03:21:55 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514096515.4667] device (enp0s31f6): link disconnected (deferring action for 4 seconds)
Dec 24 03:21:59 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514096519.9699] device (enp0s31f6): link disconnected (calling deferred action)
Dec 24 03:21:59 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514096519.9710] device (enp0s31f6): state change: activated -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed') [100 20 40]
Dec 24 03:22:00 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514096520.0040] dhcp4 (enp0s31f6): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 5343
Dec 24 03:22:00 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514096520.0041] dhcp4 (enp0s31f6): state changed bound -> done
Dec 24 03:22:00 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514096520.0141] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Dec 24 03:22:00 ThinkPad-T470s dnsmasq[2597]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Dec 24 03:22:00 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514096520.0380] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Dec 24 03:22:00 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514096520.0386] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Dec 24 03:23:05 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514096585.3880] manager: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Dec 24 03:23:05 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514096585.3880] manager: sleeping...
Dec 24 03:23:05 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514096585.3881] device (wlp58s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [30 10 37]
Dec 24 03:23:05 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514096585.3994] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Dec 24 14:34:20 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136860.2837] manager: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Dec 24 14:34:20 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136860.2837] manager: waking up...
Dec 24 14:34:20 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136860.2838] device (enp0s31f6): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [20 10 37]
Dec 24 14:34:20 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136860.3635] device (wlp58s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Dec 24 14:34:20 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136860.5599] device (enp0s31f6): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Dec 24 14:34:20 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136860.7521] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Dec 24 14:34:20 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136860.8206] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Dec 24 14:34:20 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136860.8206] device (wlp58s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available') [20 30 42]
Dec 24 14:34:23 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136863.8747] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: ready -> inactive
Dec 24 14:34:23 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136863.8747] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: ready -> inactive
Dec 24 14:34:23 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136863.9140] policy: auto-activating connection 'NETGEAR'
Dec 24 14:34:23 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136863.9150] device (wlp58s0): Activation: starting connection 'NETGEAR' (6c2a7c47-7cd1-4b73-8be7-66dc9895475f)
Dec 24 14:34:23 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136863.9152] device (wlp58s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Dec 24 14:34:23 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136863.9153] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Dec 24 14:34:23 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136863.9159] device (wlp58s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Dec 24 14:34:23 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136863.9164] device (wlp58s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'NETGEAR' has security, but secrets are required.
Dec 24 14:34:23 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136863.9166] device (wlp58s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Dec 24 14:34:23 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136863.9216] device (wlp58s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Dec 24 14:34:23 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136863.9221] device (wlp58s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Dec 24 14:34:23 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136863.9223] device (wlp58s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'NETGEAR' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Dec 24 14:34:23 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136863.9224] Config: added 'ssid' value 'NETGEAR'
Dec 24 14:34:23 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136863.9224] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Dec 24 14:34:23 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136863.9224] Config: added 'bssid' value '00:1B:2F:FC:52:64'
Dec 24 14:34:23 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136863.9224] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Dec 24 14:34:23 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136863.9224] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Dec 24 14:34:23 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136863.9225] Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
Dec 24 14:34:23 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136863.9327] sup-iface[0x2a09a00,wlp58s0]: config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Dec 24 14:34:25 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136865.1516] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> authenticating
Dec 24 14:34:25 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136865.1771] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Dec 24 14:34:25 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136865.1808] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Dec 24 14:34:25 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136865.1965] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Dec 24 14:34:25 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136865.1966] device (wlp58s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'NETGEAR'.
Dec 24 14:34:25 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136865.2045] device (wlp58s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Dec 24 14:34:25 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136865.2048] dhcp4 (wlp58s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Dec 24 14:34:25 ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[906]: <info>  [1514136865.2073] dhcp4 (wlp58s0): dhclient started with pid 12969
```

The particular problem I can see is the difference between one network "having secrets" that my laptop doesn't have, and the second one (Netgear) that has secrets my laptop seems to have.